# Getting unrecognized selector sent to class while trying to call selector as a parameter to a method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to put my current working code present in view controller to a helper class. But getting "unrecognized selector sent to class" error.

Previous View Controller:

```
UIImage *buttonImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img-settings"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIButton *buttonSetting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttonSetting setTintColor:[ColorHelper hiltiDirtyPurple]];
[buttonSetting setImage:buttonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonSetting setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 15, 24, 24)];
[buttonSetting addTarget:self action:@selector(settingPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *settingbarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonSetting];

- (void) settingPage
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settingPage" sender:nil];
}
```

Modified View Controller:

```
#import "IconsHelper.h"

UIBarButtonItem *settingbarItem = [IconsHelper setSettingButtonForSelector:@selector(settingPage) target:[ListVC self]];
```

In IconsHelper.m

```
+(UIBarButtonItem *)setSettingButtonForSelector:(SEL)selector target:(Class) classObject{
UIImage *buttonImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img-settings"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
UIButton *buttonSetting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttonSetting setTintColor:[ColorHelper hiltiDirtyPurple]];
[buttonSetting setImage:buttonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonSetting setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 15, 24, 24)];
[buttonSetting addTarget:classObject action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *settingbarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonSetting];
return settingbarItem;
```

}

Comment: Hm, `[ListVC self]` return a class, and `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` require an object, not class.

Comment: `+(UIBarButtonItem *)setSettingButtonForSelector:(SEL)selector target:(Class) classObject` change to `+(UIBarButtonItem *)setSettingButtonForSelector:(SEL)selector target:(UIViewController *) vc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this update method in IconsHelper Class

```
Updated:

    +(UIBarButtonItem *)setSettingButtonForSelector:(SEL)selector target:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    UIImage *buttonImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img-settings"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
    UIButton *buttonSetting = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonSetting setTintColor:[ColorHelper hiltiDirtyPurple]];
    [buttonSetting setImage:buttonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonSetting setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 15, 24, 24)];
    [buttonSetting addTarget:viewController action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *settingbarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonSetting];
    return settingbarItem;


    Rather than providing "Class" object, try updating parameter type to "UIViewController".
```

Also, try calling this method with following:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *settingbarItem = [IconsHelper setSettingButtonForSelector:@selector(settingPage) target:self];
```

Let me know it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try these

```
- (void)settingPage
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"settingPage" sender:self];
}
```

issue might be occur through
you have written

```
- (void) settingPage // here you have single space before method name your should write method like

- (void)settingPage
{

}
```

Hopefully you resolved your issue.
Thanks
Nirav Zalavadia